Use Pymoo for multi-objective optimization
I am a second year student. I am doing my project 1 in my course. My project 1 is to read and re-do the research in the paper. This paper is below. Because some of the parameters in the article were unclear, I set them by myself.I have implemented the code in Python (Sorry about my code, I'm not very good at coding). I used NSGA II in Pymoo to re-do the research in the paper. My code is below. But I can't run the code. Even though I learned about NSGAII in Pymoo, I still don't know where I went wrong. I only have 3 weeks to finish my project 1. So, I need your help. Thanks for reading.
Paper
My code
I can't run my code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
